# Do lack of information increases the chances of winning in probability?

Tags: probability

I came across a simple probability problem as stated below :-

You have four closed boxes each containing a single ball . We know that two boxes have black coloured balls , and other two have white coloured balls.

Now , let's name these 4 boxes as A,B,C and D .

For winning this game you have to  name the colour of ball in box C correctly .

Now,  we have two conditions :-

Condition (1)- you know that box A have white coloured ball and box B have black coloured ball . So know probability of winning this game by guessing colour of ball in box C is :- 1/2

Condition (2)- you only know that box A have White coloured ball . Now  the probability of winning , if we say that Black coloured ball is inside box C is  :- 2/3

So does this mean that in some situations if you have less information then you have more chances of winning  just like what we saw in condition 2 ?

Comment: If I buy a ticket in a lottery with only one prize and my neighbor does that too then at the moment I hear him cheering "I won a prize!!!..." I have good feelings (loving my neighbor) and (just a few) bad feelings (I definitely did not win).

Comment: information (however you define it) and winning are orthogonal concepts.  you can "know" good things, helpful things, and you can also "know" bad things such as "you ain't gonna win".

Answer (score 2):

In the condition 2 you actually have more informations about things you care (the box C): you can check that the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) in the second case is lower ($\sim 0.30$ vs $\sim 0.27$), so the outcome in the second case gives you less information, so you "already" have the "missing" information!